# Correlation between X and max(X,Y)

Tags: correlation

If I select a random value X from density f, and Y from density g, is it possible to estimate the correlation between X and max(X,Y)?

The limits are obvious: if $P(X<Y) = 1$ then $\rho = \rho_{xy}$ as max(X,Y)=Y, and if $P(X>Y) = 1$ then $\rho = 1$ as max(X,Y)=X.

Are there any approximations I can make in between given f, g, and CDFs F and G?

Comment: This is very broad. Are there some special cases you are interested in, such as $X, Y$ iid?